# FormApp of GAS - How to set correct answer to a grid item

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm trying to create Google Form Quiz using GAS. I know it's possible to set correct answers to items of check box and multiple choice. But I couldn't find any way to set correct answers to **Grid item**.
[I read Reference.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/grid-item)
Is it impossible to set correct answer to Grid item using GAS?
Thank you.

Comment: By Grid you mean **Checkbox Grid** or **Multiple Choice Grid**?

Comment: I mean Multiple Choice Grid.